# PluralSight ASP.NET Add Data?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've managed to make it through the PluralSight tutorials on ASP.NET WebForms. While I have a pretty good understanding of the information provided, I'm not sure how to add data into the database. The tutorials only went through modifying and deleting records from the DB.

What's a good video to watch to learn how to insert data into the database using entity framework? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a link to the videos that I've watched. (They're in the right column of the site)

[Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[same site](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-7) shows how to create stored procedure where it shows inserting data.. there is multiple ways to do this. u can write inline sql or create stored procedure. i prefered stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

PluralSight has really good learning series for Entity Framework: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=ef41-code-first

Comment: I dont see anything about stored procedures on inserting data on this site?